# Is it good approach to using react web view with responsive website?

Tags: react-native

Is it good approach to using react web view with responsive website? One of my client has responsive website and now he is asking for mobile app and I now react web view so will it be a good idea to use that web application in react web view?

Answer (score 0):

it definitely can be a **good** idea in this case but the answer to this question can not be unequivocal as it really depends on many factors such as client requierements, the need of using mobile hardware (GPS, camera, etc.) and so on.
There are many good articles about this subject that you can find.